# Formatting rosservice response

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, custom-message, services

I'm working on ROS MELODIC.

I would like to return as a service response a string containing a list of areas with some data.
The problem here is that I wanted to format the output so on the client side, the message could be seen clear such as:

```
Area {i}: Data <...> 

Area {i}: Data <...>
```

I have tried either with normal string or array (string[])

So my problem here is that I can't print \n or something like that in order to see each element as a new line in the output on the client. I don't know if the problem is that this cannot be achieved through this (since the message response is printed as a list), or that I'm missing something.

Also, feel free to correct me if I didn't write my post correctly, I do want to check all the recommendations but I wanted to post this so I can get an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Would it help to store the data in the string as json, then pretty print it on the receiving side using the built in json formatting options?

Comment: Hello Lucas, thanks for the answer. As I said to lazylace, the idea was to somehow format how the rosservice call output is prompted in the client terminal (I didn't create any client because I was just checking the funcionality of the service). I imagine that there's no gap on how rosservice call outputs the services response, just the fields that the response contains, but thank you for the answer!

Comment: What do you see when you have `\n` in your text response- does it print out as `\\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is preferred to create a new Message type, in your case something like `Area.msg`, and in your Service return a list of Areas.
Then, in your client, you can print it out as you wish.

You should be able though to send and print strings with new lines; remember, if your Service type looks like this:

```
---
string areas
```

then you need to print the `areas` variable:

```py
print(response.areas)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to say I wanted to know if I could somehow format the message output from calling the service from the terminal with rosrun call. This is just for debugging cases, so I didn't want to create any client node or something like it, but maybe that's the way to go.

Comment: @ÁngeLoGa ROS messages are printed to the console as YAML, as explained [here](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine). That means you can pipe the rosservice output to tools like yq in Linux, [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#quick-usage-guide) are some examples.